# returning a string in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui that when a user enters a value in an entry box a label then returns a string value based on the calculations within the function I created.

The function is working correctly when I run it in Sublime and it gives the answer I want but I want the result of the IF statement to be returned in a label but I can't see to get this to work. How would I go about linking this calculation to a label?

```
def recommend():
    try:
        in_today = int(staff.get())
        percentage = (in_today / total_fte_needed*100)
        ten_percent = 10 / 100 * total_fte_needed
        over_ten = total_fte_needed + ten_percent
        under_ten = total_fte_needed - ten_percent
        extra = (round(in_today - under_ten,2))
        loan = (round(in_today - over_ten,2))

        if in_today < under_ten :
            print('Recommend you borrow ' + str(extra) + ' fte')
        elif in_today > over_ten :
            print('More than enough staff in today, there is ' + str(loan) + ' available for loan')
        else :
            print('Enough staff in today, recommend no staff requirements or loans')
        recommend
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter whole number')
        pass
```

Comment: If you want to return the string rather than printing it, then... use `return`, not `print`.

Comment: Thanks. What would I set in the label though? Text = recommend?

Comment: `= recommend()`, you have to *call* the function to get he value it returns.

Comment: Sorry I still can't get it to work. Is it worth mentioning that a button will be pressed first to run then function but the answer needs to be displayed in a label?

Comment: This is my label which I am trying to return the result to:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  recom = tk.Label(window,text =recommend(), font=('Calibri',12)).grid(row=10,column=2,padx=8,pady=8)

Comment: do I need to set the result as a stringvar() ?

Answer (score 0):

after more research I have found an answer by setting a stringvar() called answer, and adding answer.set, instead of return before the if statement answers. I then set a textvariable = answer in the label to return the correct text statement